# SQL Dynamic Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, dynamic-sql

[image: Code Error]

I have being trying to execute this procedure:

```
go
declare @idnvarchar(max)
declare @dia nvarchar(max)
set @id='E4211537-09CD-45F2-BB5F-F20F642DE676'
set @dia='ObjectSignal_2016_05_23 '
set @sqlstring = 'Select Code From ' +@dia+ 'WHERE IdObject='+@id+''
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstring
go
```

But I'm getting the problem that is show in the image below.

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Linea 1
>
> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'CD'.

Comment: microsoft sql server ?

Comment: sql 2008 r2 MICROSOFT

Comment: So you need to cut and paste the text with an [edit] into the question. If it looks all goofy, don't worry. Someone will format it for you. The actual stored proc text is needed.

Comment: it's not reading your string as a string. The part around @id should be like `IdObject = ''' + @id + ''''`... To clarify, what you have now is `IdObject = E...` and you need `IdObject = 'E...'`.

Answer (score 0):

change the @sqlstring to following (you need to enclose the string in single quote) and also add a space before WHERE

```
set @sqlstring = 'Select Code From ' + @dia + ' WHERE idObject = ''' + @id + ''''

print @sqlstring
```

also print out the string for your own verification before executing

best method is to use sp_executesql with parameter

```
set @sqlstring = 'Select Code From ' + quotename(@dia) + ' WHERE idObject = @id' 
print @sqlstring
exec sp_executesql @sqlstring, N'@id nvarchar(max)', @id
```

Comment: Thanks so much Squirrel, and thanks for your explanation, have a really nice day :)